# Appwrite function returning permissions error

Tags: appwrite

I have a question related to the appwrite functions, I made one function following the [example in the tutorial](https://appwrite.io/docs/functions).I deployed the function and running in the appwrite console works just fine.
But I did a web app to test the function, installed the sdk and called the function... but always shows a message with the 401 code, saying the guest user doesnt have write permitions.
I return to the appwrite panel and checked all the permissions for the function, but still showing that error code with the same write permission problem for the **guest user.**

The error returned:

```
{message: "User (role: guest) missing scope (execution.write)", code: 401,…}
code: 401
message: "User (role: guest) missing scope (execution.write)"
type: "general_unauthorized_scope"
version: "0.13.4
```

I looked in the example in the docs and I didn't found the place where I can indicate a user for the function call in the SDK.

I'm stuck in this problem for 5 days, someone know how to solve or can give me some direction?

Appwrite version 0.13.4 running at a digital ocean server.

Answer (score 5):

Ahoi there~

What you're missing is either an active session through logging in:

```
const sdk = new Appwrite();

sdk
    .setEndpoint('https://[HOSTNAME_OR_IP]/v1') // Your API Endpoint
    .setProject('5df5acd0d48c2') // Your project ID
;

let promise = sdk.account.createSession('email@example.com', 'password');

promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // Success
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error); // Failure
});
```

Or you can go to the "Settings" tab of your function and change the execution permission to include "role:guest".

I discourage the use of the second option for obvious security reasons (everyone can execute your function).

Cheers,

Vincent

Comment: Hello Vicent,
The first suggestion works, with the createSession method.
The unsafe suggestion doesn't, I set the role to role:guest and the 401 error with the same message still happening.
But I'll use the first solution. Thanks!

Comment: That... sounds like a bug! I'll go file this as an issue, but regardless, having a session is recommended anyway. For security reasons :D

Comment: I believe this is the intended behavior. No unauthenticated writing to the database ever, meaning you need a session. It should work fine if you authenticate your user with account.createAnonymousSession(). https://appwrite.io/docs/client/account?sdk=web-default#accountCreateAnonymousSession

Comment: You're right. That is the behavior. No writes unless there is an active session :)

Comment: Okay In my case I want to store user into "User" collection in some database simultaneously  Signing up the user. What should be the Approach ?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem a few weeks ago. Appwrite does not log you in or generate any session token for your appwrite functions. It just executes them like any other program. Therefor, you have to authenticate yourself first. You can do that by logging in (like Vincent Ge answered) or by using an api token. The later gives you the option to give the function exactly the permission it needs to do its job. Later on you can pass the api key via environment variables to your function.

To get started just head over to api-keys on the appwrite dashboard and click on "add api-key". Toggle the settings your function needs and generate the api key. Save the key and head over to your function.
You can set up environment variables for your function at the bottom of your function-settings. Set up the api key for example as the key `APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY` with your function key as the value.

Now access the key in your function code and use `client.setKey` to use the key for each call to appwrite.

Cheers, Nico

Answer (score 0):

Project ID is required,  in header add *X-Appwrite-Project*

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > API Keys,

- If you don't have any API key then create one with permissions you need
- If you have already an API key then you can give that API key those permissions you need

Answer (score -1):

You need to have an active session in order to be able to execute the function, are you logged in?